# Puppeteer - how to do make click on a link without navigation

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I was just wondering. I have an event on click on a link but the link also navigates to another page. I want to use puppeteer to click the link like this:

```
page.click('a.link')
```

But after the click I would like to prevent the navigation and just console log the event. Is there any way to click a link without further navigation using puppeteer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your best option would be to intercept the request to load a new page and cancel it.
[page.setRequestInterception](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-pagesetrequestinterceptionvalue)

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on('request', request => {
  if (request.isNavigationRequest() && request.redirectChain().length !== 0) {
    request.abort();
  } else {
    request.continue();
  }
});

await page.click('a.link');
await page.setRequestInterception(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to preventDefault on link click, like this:

```
<a href="https://google.com" id="no-track">click me </a>

$('#no-track').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('clicked: '+$(this).attr('href'));
            return false;
});
```

Comment: the same for puppeteer triggering the click.